# I'm using JavaScript & Regex to build objects around links. Need some clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, youtube

To clarify - I've built a comment system that sanitizes all HTML and displays it as plaintext to prevent trolling, cross-site scripting, etc.

On top of that, I have javascript that runs after the page loads, and detects DIRECT links to Youtube and Imgur content, then builds the appropriate player/frame/tag to display that content.

Here is my example code:

```
<div class="video imgur">
https://i.imgur.com/Ym7MypF.jpg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
</div>
```

And script:

```
$('.video').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});

$('.imgur').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:i\.)?(?:imgur\.com|)\/(.+)/g, '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/$1">');

});
```

I can get one to work without the other - however - running both on the same page invariably produces broken tags and links like this, depending on the order:

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https:&lt;img src=" https:="" i.imgur.com="" www.youtube.com="" embed="" t-zrx8984sc"="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Why won't my code differentiate between Imgur and Youtube and handle them separately? I'm new at Regex and cannot tell what I'm doing wrong. If anyone could sort me out I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Imgur regex matches too many URLs, e.g.:

- https://example.com
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foobar
- https://imgur.com/foobar

Try using this regex instead: `/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:i\.)?(?:imgur\.com)\/(.+)/g`

Comment: This worked immediately and on several test comments. Thank you.